# Positioning of HTML elements in Tailwind css

Tags: html, css, vue.js, css-position, tailwind-css

I'm trying to learn `tailwind-css` or I would say learning `css` where I'm struggling with the position of elements. Working on `Vue js` components.

I achieved the designing few of the elements so far:

[image: Home screen]

[image: feature page]

[image: banner page]

[image: description]

I want to add some shapes or designs inside the `banner/dark-blue` area and then would add some widget-box inside of it. My code look something like this:

```
<div class="bg-white block">
    <nav-bar></nav-bar>
    <div class="hidden md:block w-2/5 top-0 left-0">
        <img src="/nits-assets/images/body_shape.png" alt="shape" align="left">
    </div>
    <div class="hidden md:block">
        <img src="/nits-assets/images/body_shape_2.png" alt="shape" align="right">
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <div class="absolute w-full top-0 pl-12 pr-12 pt-40">
            <slider></slider>
            <div class="flex justify-around">
                <card></card>
                <card></card>
                <card></card>
                <card></card>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <div class="bg-white overlflow-hidden">
            <div class="relative">
                <img src="/nits-assets/images/screenshot_banner.png" alt="screenshot_banner" align="center">
                <img class="absolute top-0 left-0" src="/nits-assets/images/pattern_1.png" alt="banner" align="left">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <feature></feature>
</div>
```

For reference to the components code: https://github.com/nitish1986/sample_website

My approach was to fix position of the parent element or make it relative then position the shapes with absolute positioning respective to its parent element but whenever I try to put absolute position the shapes reaches to the top of the website. It is not taking respective positioning

```
<div class="bg-white overlflow-hidden">
    <div class="relative">
        <img src="/nits-assets/images/screenshot_banner.png" alt="screenshot_banner" align="center">
        <img class="absolute top-0 left-0" src="/nits-assets/images/pattern_1.png" alt="banner" align="left">
    </div>
</div>
```

How can achieve this positioning? I want to achieve something like this:

[image]

Any better approach into it are most welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Is using background images with the content you desire an option? If not, why?

Comment: If you're able to get your code on JSFiddle or codepen I'll gladly take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a lot of research work on my issue, I found out that my absolute element is taking all the space needed for me. I came to know that I have to define an empty space or define the height of the div which is exactly consumed by my absolute elements. Since in my code I have a very long absolute element, so the only thing can cover is empty div space.

```
<div class="bg-white block">
    <nav-bar></nav-bar>
    <div class="hidden md:block w-2/5 top-0 h-auto">
        <img src="/nits-assets/images/body_shape.png" alt="shape" align="left">
    </div>
    <div class="hidden md:block h-auto">
        <img src="/nits-assets/images/body_shape_2.png" alt="shape" align="right">
    </div>
    <div class="block bg-white h-screen">
        <div class="relative">
            <div class="absolute w-full top-0 pl-12 pr-12 pt-40">
                <slider></slider>
                <div class="flex justify-around">
                    <card></card>
                    <card></card>
                    <card></card>
                    <card></card>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block mt-48 p-56">
        <div class="p-2 w-full h-100"></div>
    </div>
    <feature></feature>
    <preview></preview>
    <about-us></about-us>
</div>
```

So in my code I kept empty space with:

```
<div class="block mt-48 p-56">
    <div class="p-2 w-full h-100"></div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps someone. Thanks